# cakephp 2 How to set input name dynamically

Tags: php, cakephp

i need to set 30 or 29 or 30 or 28 input , depending on the current month,  and to get the text from those inputs after a post.
in my view i did like this :

```
echo $this->Form->create('Cra');
foreach ($MonthDaysM as $i) : ?>
<td><?php echo $this->Form->input($i, array('label'=>false));?></td>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</form>
```

and in the controller

```
if ($this->request->is('post')) {




$date = $this->request->data['Cra'][$i];
```

.....

But doesn't work, because the name of the input should not be a variable. but how can i get the contents of my inputs ????

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to do here. What are the inputs for?

Comment: Also what version of Cake are you working with?

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the input field name and then add index as follows:

```
<?php foreach ($MonthDaysM as $i) : ?>
    <td><?php echo $this->Form->input('your_field_name.' . $i, array('label'=>false));?></td>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Then in controller check `$this->request->data['Cra']['your_field_name']`. It should be an array.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very clear how your model 'Cra' is defined, but if you want to get the contents of your inputs:

In your view:

```
<?php for($i = 1; $i <= date('t'); $i++) : ?>
<td><?php echo $this->Form->input('Cra.days.'.$i, array('label'=>false)); ?></td>
<?php endfor; ?>
```

Then, in your controller you can access the content of your days array this way:

```
if($this->request->is('post')){
  $days = $this->request->data['Cra']['days'];
}
```

For example, the results for 'days' array, would be:

```
Array
(
  [1] => Day 1 content
  [2] => Day 2 content
  [3] => Day 3 content
  ...
)
```

Hope this can help.